# Using php to download the android apk file,but downloaded apk can not be installed

Tags: php, nginx, download, header, apk

I used php to download the android apk file,by headers. First I add `"application/vnd.android.package-archive apk;"` to file "mime.types" of nginx and my code is :

```
$path = "XXXX" . $_GET['apk'];
Header("Content-type: application/vnd.android.package-archive");
header("Content-Length:" . filesize($path));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . basename($_GET['apk']) . "'");
ob_end_flush();
readfile($path);
```

it can download successfully, and the size of apk is right. But the apk can't be installed when I run "adb install",the error is:

> adb: failed to install 1540319993.apk: Failure
>   [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse
>   /data/app/vmdl754242520.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]

when I use scp to get the apk file. It can be installed,so my apk file is right.Any one has some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have change the ob_end_flush() to

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

and it worked.